# EXCEL IF AND VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I am having trouble in an IF STATEMENT, comparing the output of a VLOOKUP with any value object.  For example

```
=TRIM(IF(OR(TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE))=K1,TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE))=K2),BE11,TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE))))
```

K1, K2 are value cells

NO errors are produced just incorrect values

Comment: you can't compare  TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE)) with a value or value cell

Comment: you actually can. Are you getting an error? to repeat above "what seems to be the issue?" What are the data types you are comparing? numbers? text? combination?

Comment: No errors, just incorrect values, trying to compare numbers

Answer (score 1):

Not much to go on but having a guess at your data and incorrect values.

You are testing equality here:

```
TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE))=K1
```

The TRIM will cast to a string if cell K1 is evaluate as a number then the expression will return false. My assumption here is that the values in K1 and also K2 may be evaluate as numbers.

I suggest that you try evaluating K1 and K2 as strings eg.

```
TRIM(VLOOKUP(AI11,G15:I90,3,FALSE))=TRIM(K1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare numbers, don't use Trim, since it supposed to return a string.
Try Value instead, which will return a number.
If you're using 2007 or later, you could also include an IFERROR to avoid the #N/A or other errors. If using older version, it's very simple to write your own IFERROR.